# After adding the wpf user control, why element hosts still cannot find the wpf user control

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have adding the wpf user control and build the project. However elementhost still cannot find the user control. Any step I missed?

BTW, I am using UI with Visual Studio 2008. Using code is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the WPF control and assign it to ElementHost.Child:

```
this.elementHost1.Child = new MyWPFProject.MyWPFControl();
```